# Why did the Gallowwalkers need to reskin when Wesley Snipes did not?

Tags: plot-device, undead, gallowwalkers

Wesley Snipes

> after being killed and resurrected kills the outlaws that killed his wife. The problem is, he's cursed: his undead (Gallowwalkers) victims rise and pursue him in a seemingly endless cycle of violence. In the process, the Gallowwalkers skin and wear the local populations skin as if it was their own.

---

> You see a skinless GW with no signs of trauma to the structure of it's body. He soon cloaks himself with another epidermus. I mention that because if the skin was torn up, shot, stabbed, or whatever when the GW was killed, there would likely be tale tell injuries to the body itself. The GW healed before resurection.

Why did the [Gallowwalkers](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0829176/) need to reskin when Aman (Wesley Snipes) did not?